# Secondary Replica SQL Server(Availability Groups )

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

I have two bases in a group on SQL Server.
The first one is primary and the second is the replica.
I want to connect to the replica (from a simple C # application) if the primary one falls.
How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your databases are in an Availability Group (AG), you should point your application to the Listener for the AG. This is a network name that will always point to the primary server for the AG.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 Enterprise and later versions support backup compression. When creating a log shipping configuration, you can control the backup compression behavior of log backups and if you already have a Replica then you can configure it When an availability failover occurs, existing persistent connections to the availability are terminated and the client must establish a new connection in order to continue working with the same primary database or read-only secondary database. For more information.

[Configure Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/configure-log-shipping-sql-server)

[Secondary Database Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/secondary-database-settings)

[Application Failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover)

Comment: Thanks!But in simple words I could connect to the replica (from an application in C #) if the primary one falls?

Comment: Then you can try with Application Failover. a backup read-only connection or something alike

Comment: Accept the answer to highlight your best efforts to other users.